# Why do we need the gamma parameter in the polynomial kernel of SVMs?

Tags: machine-learning, svm, kernel-trick

The polynomial kernel is sometimes defined as just:
$$
K(x,y):=(\left<x,y\right>+c)^d
$$
with two parameters: the degree $d$ and constant coefficient $c$.

But others (e.g., [libsvm](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/), and [sklearn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#svm-kernels) which uses libsvm) include a scaling parameter $\gamma$:
$$
K^\prime(x,y):=(\gamma \left<x,y\right>+r)^d
$$

Now it's fairly easy to see that this is redundant. Choose $r=\gamma c$, and we get
$$
K^\prime(x,y):=(\gamma \left<x,y\right>+\gamma c)^d=\gamma^d(\left<x,y\right>+c)^d=\gamma^d K(x,y)
$$

But a constant scaling factor on the kernel does not matter for SVMs, does it?

I can imagine the following arguments: (1) consistency with RBF, where $\gamma$ is essential to scale the Gaussians (but I doubt you can choose the same value for both); (2) to avoid certain numerical range problems (c.f., libsvm guide mentions that the polynomial kernel can be problematic, but so can RBF) (3) other algorithms that do not learn weights - but which other algorithms work well with kernels and do *not* have weights to optimize?

Is there any theoretical reason why we should include $\gamma$ when teaching kernels?